# C# Color Matching

Tags: c#, colors

Can you help me with my color matching

I tried to search some codes it didn't work well

My logic is like below, with adjustable tolerance like 5% or 10% closest to color:

```
Red and Light Red = True    
Red and Dark Red = True
Red and black = False
```

here's my code but it didn't work very well

```
public static bool MatchArgb(int Argb1, int Argb2, int tolerance)
{
    Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(Argb1);
    Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(Argb2);

    return Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R) <= tolerance ^
           Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G) <= tolerance ^
           Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B) <= tolerance;
}

public static bool MatchColor(Color c1, Color c2, int tolerance)
{
    return Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R) <= tolerance ^
           Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G) <= tolerance ^
           Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B) <= tolerance;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is a good idea to check how this is done in Paint.NET. I found a clone of it and the corresponding source code here: [Pinta/Flood Tool](https://github.com/PintaProject/Pinta/blob/master/Pinta.Tools/Tools/FloodTool.cs)

```
    private static bool CheckColor (ColorBgra a, ColorBgra b, int tolerance)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int diff;

        diff = a.R - b.R;
        sum += (1 + diff * diff) * a.A / 256;

        diff = a.G - b.G;
        sum += (1 + diff * diff) * a.A / 256;

        diff = a.B - b.B;
        sum += (1 + diff * diff) * a.A / 256;

        diff = a.A - b.A;
        sum += diff * diff;

        return (sum <= tolerance * tolerance * 4);
    }
```